# different view source content in browser and from httpwebrequest in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape content from this page: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&biw=1920&bih=956&tbm=shop&q=Xenon+12640&oq=Xenon+12640&aq=f&gs_l=serp.3...3743.3743.0.3905.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.ekh..0.0.Hq3XS7AxFDU&sei=Dr_MT_WOM6nO2AWE25mTCA&gbv=2

The problem I am experiencing is that opening that url in a browser I get everything I need to scrape but scraping the same link in the code, two (important) pieces are missing, the reviews number and the ratings, below the price and the seller info. 
Here is the screenshot from the internal web client in c#: http://gyazo.com/908a37c7f70712fba1f82ec90a604d4d.png?1338822369

Here is the code with which I am trying to get the content:

```
    public string navGet(string inURL, CookieContainer inCookieContainer, bool GZip, string proxyAddress, int proxyPort,string proxyUserName, string proxyPassword)
    {
        try
        {
        this.currentUrl = inURL;           
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(inURL);
    webRequest.Timeout = this.TimeOutSetting;
    webRequest.CookieContainer = inCookieContainer;

    if (proxyAddress == "0" || proxyPort == 0)
    { }
    else
    {
        webRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyAddress, proxyPort);
        // Use login credentials to access proxy
        NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(proxyUserName, proxyPassword);
        webRequest.Proxy.Credentials = networkCredential;
    }

    Uri destination = webRequest.Address;
    webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
    webRequest.Method = "GET";
    webRequest.Accept = "*/*";
    webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us");
    if (GZip)
    {
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    }
        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; FunWebProducts; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";

        webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";         
        //webRequest.CookieContainer.Add(inCookieContainer.GetCookies(destination));

    try
    {
        string strSessionID = inCookieContainer.GetCookies(destination)["PHPSESSID"].Value;
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", "USER_OK=1;PHPSESSID=" + strSessionID);
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {

    }
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        if (webRequest.HaveResponse)
        {
            // First handle cookies
            foreach(Cookie retCookie in webResponse.Cookies)
            {
                bool cookieFound = false;
                foreach(Cookie oldCookie in inCookieContainer.GetCookies(destination))
                {
                    if (retCookie.Name.Equals(oldCookie.Name))
                    {
                        oldCookie.Value = retCookie.Value;
                        cookieFound = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!cookieFound)
                    inCookieContainer.Add(retCookie);
            }                


            // Read response
        Stream responseStream = responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();



        if (webResponse.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
        {
            responseStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        }
        else if (webResponse.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
        {
            responseStream = new DeflateStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        }

        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

        string responseString = stream.ReadToEnd();
            stream.Close();
            this.currentUrl = webResponse.ResponseUri.ToString();
            this.currentAddress = webRequest.Address.ToString();               
            setViewState(responseString);
            return responseString;
        }
        throw new Exception("No response received from host.");
        return "An error was encountered";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("NavGet:" + ex.Message);
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it happens because  the reviews number and the ratings are generated dynamically using Java Script (probably AJAX or something else). In this case you need to analyze additional traffic that takes place when the page is loaded in the browser and find where this data is transfered or analize JavaScript code to see how it's generated.